# Looking for $F$ where we know the $n$th derivative and the solution for $b=1$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta

The few steps before equation 3.20 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1001/1001.2835.pdf) imply that
$$\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{H_k^{(n)}}{n}x^n}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(1-x)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k+1-x)}$$
Adjusting the starting point and then taking the limit $k\to\infty$, we have
$$\exp\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac{\zeta(n)}{n}x^n}\right)=e^{-\gamma x}\Gamma(1-x)$$
We can then say
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac{\zeta(n)}{n}x^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\frac{n!}{n+2}\zeta(n+2)}{n!}x^{n+2}}=\ln(e^{-\gamma x}\Gamma(1-x))=-\gamma x+\ln(\Gamma(1-x))$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\frac{n!}{n+2}\zeta(n+2)}{n!}x^{n}}=\frac{-\gamma x+\ln(\Gamma(1-x))}{x^2}$$
And so we have
$$\frac{n!}{n+2}\zeta(n+2)=\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{-\gamma x+\ln(\Gamma(1-x))}{x^2}\right|_{x=0}$$
I was hoping that we could use this to answer my main question:

Can we find the function $F$ where for some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$\frac{n!}{n+2}\zeta(b(n+2))=\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}F(x)\right|_{x=0}$$

Comment: This follows directly from $\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} = -\gamma-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{z+n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula

Comment: It works only for integer values of $\zeta$.  Taking $F(x) = \zeta(s,x)$, its derivatives (in $x$) around $x=1$ are given by $\zeta(n+s)$

Comment: I'm not really sure how this helps me answer my question. @user1952009